# Unable to toggle angular material side-nav for the first time when you open in new browser window

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular5 and angular material, when I open my app in a new browser window I am not able to toggle my sidenav, But When I reload the same window -I am able to toggle side-nav. I am curious to know why It is not opening for the first time?

I tried using side-nav API's like toggle, opened etc, even changed my html structure still issue.

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav  #sideNav mode="over" [position]="nav_position">
      <div class="drawer-container center-content">
          <div class="header">
              <span class="title">{{navLabel}}</span> 
              <span class="gray-label padding-rt-12" (click)="reset()">Reset</span>
           </div>
           <div class="content">
               <app-contact-preference [getAction]="actions.asObservable()"></app-contact-preference>
           </div>
           <div class="footer">
               <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" class="cancel" (click)="toggle()">Close</button>
               <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="save()">Save</button>
           </div>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content class="center-content">
      <app-title (sideEvent)="catchEvent()"></app-title>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

```
//////////////////
@ViewChild('sideNav') public sidenav: MatSidenav;

 catchEvent(){
    this.sidenav.toggle();
  }
```

Let me know, If any other data is required from my side, really looking for your help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create Stackblitz of your problem?